# Cocoapods 'libcrypto.a and libssl.a' conflict

Tags: ios, cocoapods

```
Using MJRefresh (3.1.12)
Installing NIMSDK (4.0.0)
Using Reachability (3.1.1)
Using SDWebImage (3.8.2)
Using SSZipArchive (1.8.1)
Using SVProgressHud (2.0.4)
Using SnapKit (3.0.0)
Using SwiftyJSON (3.1.4)
Using TZImagePickerController (1.7.9)
Using Toast (3.1.0)
Using Zip (0.6.0)

[!] The 'Pods-GXTax' target has libraries with conflicting names: libcrypto.a and libssl.a
```

When I use cocopods shows the error shown. Does anyone know how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Post actual code, not images of code. Thanks!

Comment: Please do not post images, post code

Comment: Remove image. Format thext for better readability. Add a tag

Answer (score 1):

- Find pod cache directory like this:

```
pod cache list | grep NIMSDK
```

Output will be like the following:

```
NIMSDK:
    Spec:    /Users/username/Library/Caches/CocoaPods/Pods/Specs/Release/NIMSDK/4.2.podspec.json
    Pod:     /Users/username/Library/Caches/CocoaPods/Pods/Release/NIMSDK/4.2.0-b6a8f
```

- Go to the Pod directory and find `libcrypto.a` and `libssl.a`
- Delete conflicting files `libcrypto.a` and `libssl.a`
- Rerun `pod install`